# JASFinder and CKEDITOR returning url

Tags: php, javascript, ckeditor

I was very desparate to get an answer somewhere else, I hope somone can help me here. I am using JASFinder as uploader for CKEDITOR in my website.

I have one little but big problem. I am using the php connector and I have set the config.php as below:

```
$Config['UserFilesPath'] = SITE_URL.'/gallery/' ;
```

`SITE_URL` is just a constant for `http://127.0.0.1`

the problem is when I select the uploaded image with JASFinder in CKEDITOR, the path that will be returned always contains a dot (.) at its beggining, so I have to go into image properties and remove that dot from the url manually. so a returned url from jasfinder to ckeditor will be like `.http://127.0.0.1/gallery/file.jpg`

I am wondering if somone knows the fix to remove that extra dot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I find the soloution, hope it will help others :P

Open the `filemanager.js`in `scripts` folder of JASFinder, locate line number 509 you will find this line of code:

```
        Url : '.' + urlDir + filename,
```

The fix is just to remove that dot. this iwll be the result:

```
        Url : '' + urlDir + filename,
```

BUT! KCFinder is a much better alternative to JASFinder.